# How significant is a 5-10 mb drop in pressure over a 20 minute period?

Tags: meteorology, barometric-pressure, instrumentation

I would be interested in seeing how significant a 5-10 mb drop in pressure would be at the surface, and 80 m in the air. The temporal scale would be 20 minutes. If the pressure starts to steadily increase after the drop in pressure, would this hint that the instruments are measuring data incorrectly, or is there something else at play?

Comment: What's the context? Just thinking if you're measuring outside a building, a change in wind direction might cause eddies that might result in a pattern like that. Or if you're in a balloon or glider, it could be due to drifting into a thermal or something.

Comment: The answer below reinforces the comment above. What is the context?

Answer (score 6):

On the synoptic scale (thinking along the lines of cyclones, weather fronts etc.), then that's a pretty significant drop in that amount of time.

A **bomb** or **explosive cycogenesis** in meteorological terms is defined as a drop of at least 24mb in 24 *hours*, so your observation easily fits this description of being a significant rapid pressure change. There's a list of similar events [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_deepening).

You ask what the significance would be at the surface, and only 80m up, which makes me think you might be talking about smaller scales (perhaps?), in which case @naught101 is right in suspecting small scale eddies from buildings could be causing the surprising readings. 80m isn't really going change the significance of an observation that much on synoptic/meso -scales.

*Sources*:

http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Bomb

[Synoptic-Dynamic Climatology of the "Bomb"](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/1520-0493%281980%29108%3C1589%3ASDCOT%3E2.0.CO%3B2)

Comment: This case is definitely in between meso and microscale meteorology. The only issue with the eddy idea is that the instruments are located in an isolated flat field, so it couldn't have been mechanical turbulence that played a role.